# VF Page Datepicker Not working

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to display just year using the datepicker script. Not able to get the year display format:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0">
<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: " yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});

</script>

<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
 <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>Year</h1>
            </div> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!User.Year__c}" styleClass="form-control" type="text" html-placeholder="Enter Your Year"  id="datepicker" />
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

**Expected:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have all other requirements, i.e loaded scripts, set the params correct etc.....

your issue is the ID of the input field is not simply `datepicker`. When you add elements to the DOM using visual force components, VF appends values to the ID corresponding to the document tree it creates.

Easiest way to resolve is to use the **Ends With** selector:

```
$("[id$=datepicker]")
```

On your function to initialize the date picker on the element.

You can also use the **$Component** global merge field:

> A global merge field type to use when referencing a Visualforce
>   component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm

An Example:

```
document.getElementById(
    "{!$Component.theBlock.theSection.theSectionItem.theText}")
```